# Has the ILDASM tool been updated since .Net 1.1?

Tags: .net

Microsoft's ILDASM is a very useful tool for looking at .Net assemblies.  It has both command-line and GUI interfaces.

Every time a new version of .Net comes out there is documentation describing the current ILDASM, and a link next to it for earlier versions, for example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1.aspx

... but these documents only describe the command-like interface.    I'm not much of a typist so I gravitate toward GUI interfaces.   But the only documentation I can find on the GUI version of ILDASM dates back to .Net 1.1 .  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa309387%28VS.71%29.aspx

So has ILDASM changed since 1.1 in any way that I need to be aware of as a GUI user of it, and if so are those changes documented anywhere?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to simply look at decompiled .NET assemblies, may I suggest [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/)?

Comment: I can recommend [JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) (also free like ILSpy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been no significant changes to ildasm.exe since at least .NET 2.0 that I know of, the last version of .NET that had a major change in the IL format.  The GUI has been stable longer.  There otherwise just isn't much need to change the program, it relies on the underlying native COM interface that allows any program to read .NET metadata, IMetaDataImport.  IMetaDataImport2 is the .NET 2.0 version of that interface.  No change in .NET 4 although the implementation of interface surely was changed.  Also the interface used by decompilers like Reflector and ILSpy.

Not sure why you are asking this question, but you can get the source code for ildasm from the [SSCLI20 distribution](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4917).  You'll find it back in the clr/src/ildasm folder.  It is written in C++.